# Installing TA-Lib on python 3.7

Tags: python, installation, ta-lib

I've read through posts regarding installing TA-Lib in Python but without success.  Here's what I've done so far:

1. Since my Python is 3.7.3, I downloaded the file `TA_Lib-0.4.17-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` 
   from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib, and put it under the base folder.
2. I then went to Anaconda Prompt and type `pip install TA_Lib-0.4.17-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`, and here's what I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.download import DownloadCommand
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\download.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.prepare import RequirementPreparer
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions import (
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions.source import SourceDistribution
ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution' from 'pip._internal.distributions.source' (C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\source\__init__.py)
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try this and let us know if this works for you.....

1. curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
2. python get-pip.py

Answer (score 0):

Installing via conda works fine for me (conda install -c conda-forge ta-lib). I also containerized my package (for https://www.gammathworks.com/gammathspot) via docker so I can use the same container across platforms and not worry about platform-specific installation issues. Check the README at https://github.com/salylgw/gammath_spot