# pip install netifaces gives me an error (windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x, installation, python-netifaces

I try to install netifaces package but I recieve an error as below:
[image]

I searched the internet including this site, and founded some solutions that didn't work for me, like [this one](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7217), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426409/installing-ta-lib-on-python-3-7) and [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7211).

As the sites recommended I double checked the path is correct, you can see the path here: 
[image]

I cleared the anaconda cache by enter command (in cmd):

```
conda clean --all
```

I even tried to use PyCharm but since the installation failed I can't use the netifaces...

WTF i'm missing?

*** EDIT ***

I did a virtual env by the instructions on uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/… like @Azeem suggested and got the following error:
[image: error]
[image: pip-install]

I have connda V. 4.7.12

Comment: Create a venv, activate it, upgrade pip and try to install your desired package in active virtual env.

Comment: @Azeem, I can't pip install.
I enter to the venv, but when I do the pip install I get an error "could not find a version the satisfies the requirment netifaces....
I'm pip version 19.0.3
How can I attach the photo I snaped to see the process I did?

Comment: Please follow the link to create venv using conda:
https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/

Comment: Or try this using conda:
conda install -c conda-forge netifaces

Comment: To update your pip inside your venv:
pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
1. uninstall anacaonda and python
2. restart (just to be sure)
3. install anaconda in a diffrent directory that is not hidden, and WITH the option "Add anaconda to the system path environment variale"

I don't know what helped, It's logic that the "add to path" helped.